# Read Ydata from video frame

Tags: java, android, video

I want to read Y(Luminance data from consecutive frames of an .mp4 file) in java code.
How can i be able to do that.It is good if i don't have to use any media library like
ffmpeg/opencv.Actually i am applying the following simple blockiness algorithm on the .mp4 file.

1.Luminance gradient image is first segmented into blocks of 32×32 pixels.
2.Each block is then Fast Fourier transformed into frequency domain.
3.Following this, we measure the ratio of the sum of harmonics to the sum of all the AC components,in both the horizontal and vertical orientations. The ratios serve as an indication of the severity of the blocking artefacts.

Any pointers on code samples(fft,measuring sum of harmonics of fft)

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 1):

"It is good if i don't have to use any media library like ffmpeg/opencv" That would be good, But essentially impossible. Video is highly compressed, like a zip file but way more complex. And like a zip files, you can not see inside without decompressing it. To decompress, I recommend using libavformat/libavcodec from the ffmpeg library. use libswscale (also from ffmpeg) to convert your frame to YUV (if your codec uses a different color space). and fftw for analysis.

Good luck, this is a big project.